# "Недоступна" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

> Эта особенность поведения почти не доступна нашему взгляду.

НЕ слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть пояснительные слова со значением степени качества (ПОЧТИ, ОЧЕНЬ, весьма, крайне, абсолютно, совершенно, совсем, слишком и др), НЕ с прилагательным пишется слитно.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае ***не*** с прилагательным пишется ВМЕСТЕ, т.к. здесь утверждается ''недоступность''. Если нужно подчеркнуть отрицание( т.е. отрицание доступности), тогда нужно раздельное написание. Однако для для этого должен располагать контекст.

Дополнение

Спасибо за замечание! ***Не заметил!***

Comment: Серж:  "В вашем случае не с прилагательным пишется раздельно, т.к. здесь утверждается ''недоступность''."===
Гм... "раздельно"?...т.к. утверждается(!) ''недоступность''?

Comment: Простите, Серж, всё-таки поправлю:не ВМЕСТЕ, а СЛИТНО.Вместе ходят в театр, а пишут слитно.